# Retrieving data from PHP using AJAX to send to different PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok so I have:

A PHP file that queries a database and displays the results of the query,
a HTML file that displays the results using AJAX and
another PHP file that I need to send the data from the first PHP file to.

How can I do this?

My first PHP file displays:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
    if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
$str_shopresult .= "<div class='result'><a id='shoplink' href='#shop'><strong><div id='hiddenid'>" .
$row['id'] . "</div>" .  
$row['name']  . "</strong><br><br>" .
$row['address'] . "<br><br><i>" . 
$row['sold'] . "</i></div></a>"; 
}
```

So the AJAX brings this in and displays it in the HTML. Is there a way of sending the ID field when the link is clicked so that it can be used in another PHP file to display the data for that specific ID.

```
$( "#result" ).click(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "external-data/shop.php",
    data: $("#hiddenid"),
    success: function (data) {
    $("#individualshop").load("external-data/shop.php");
    }
});
```

So that the data from the #hiddendiv ($row ['ID']) will be sent to the new PHP file. This isn't working.

shop.php has the code:

```
//get shop ID
    $shopid = $_POST['ID'];

    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE ID='$shopid'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
        if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $str_shops .= "<div class='searchresult'><strong>" . 
    $row['name']  . "</strong><br><br>" .
    $row['address'] . "<br><br><i>" . 
    $row['sold'] . "</i></div>"; 
 }
```

But I'm not sure how to retrieve the ID?

Basically I need to be able to click on each search result and have another PHP file bring in specific data associated with the ID of the search result. Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by 'This isn't working'? what are the contents on _external-data/shop.php_?

Comment: @leonardo I updated the above post, sorry!

Comment: you retrieve the ID by passing this: `data: { id: $("#hiddenid")},` instead of `data: $("#hiddenid"),`

Comment: @Kathryn see my answer, and what is this `$("#individualshop").load("external-data/shop.php");` for in ajax success?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL it is to bring in the result of the shop.php query but I think I should be using $("#individualshop").html(data); ?

Comment: @Kathryn Yes exactly, I have already stated in my answer. And do not forget to return html in `shop.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want but this is one way.

This is your first php file. I've added an onclick listener to it so when a user clicks a row it will fire a JavaScript passing the $row['id'] variable.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
$str_shopresult .= "<div onclick='someFunction(" . $row['id'] . ")' class='result'><div id='shoplink' href='#shop'><strong><div id='hiddenid'>" .
$row['id'] . "</div>" .  
$row['name']  . "</strong><br><br>" .
$row['address'] . "<br><br><i>" . 
$row['sold'] . "</i></div></div>"; 
}
```

Then add this script to the header of the page.

```
<script>
function someFunction(d){
var response = httpGet("http://yourdomain.com/newphpfile.php?page_id=" +d);

document.getElementById('someResultArea').innerHTML = response;

}
function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open( "POST", theUrl, false );
            xmlHttp.send();
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

Then your new php file should do something like this.

newphpfile.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

$page_id = strip_tags($_GET['page_id']);

$processResult = 'handle your result';

echo $processResult;

?>
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: It won't let me add the onclick function in the php file for some reason

Comment: I fixed my syntax. Try it again.

Comment: Thank you. Although when I click the result and echo the $page_id it comes through as undefined

Comment: Where is it undefined? When your first page comes up you should be able to inspect the html of the row and see if the correct row Id was written in the listener. Also, you can flip to the console tab and watch your JS fire to see if that's where the problem was.

Comment: In the new php file, when I click a result and echo the id in the new php file it simply says undefined. When inspecting the element it says <div onclick=someFunction()> with nothing in the brackets and then on the new page it says undefined. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: http://cs11ke.icsnewmedia.net/DVPrototype/#location this is the link to see it in action, if you click one of the shops it brings up undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
$( "#result" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "external-data/shop.php",
        data: "ID=" + $("#hiddenid"),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#individualshop").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** Do not forget to return html in `shop.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the clicked element id by using either javascript or jquery, and put it in the GET parameters on the php link

the ajax target would be ajax.php?id=test

Then get the value of `id` via `$_GET['id']`